# Laravel Eloquent getting related content with multiple columns

Tags: php, laravel

In my application I am trying to create a related Events section where all events related to a specific event are shown.

**I had this query**

```
public function show($id)
{
    // The current event
    $event = Event::find($id);

    // Find related, upcoming events
    $tags = $event->tags;

    $relatedEvents = Event::where('startDate', '>=', Carbon::now())
    ->where(function ($query) use ($event) {
        $query->where('hostedBy', $event->hostedBy);
        $query->orWhere('type', $event->hostedBy);
        $query->orWhere('category', $event->hostedBy);
        $query->orWhere('sector', $event->hostedBy);
    })
    ->toSql();

    dd($relatedEvents);
}
```

**Which output he following SQL**

`"select * from`events`where`startDate`>= ? and (`hostedBy`= ? or`type`= ? or`category`= ? or`sector`= ?)"`

**I then tried this**

```
/**
 * Display the specified resource.
 *
 * @param  \App\Event  $event
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function show($id)
{
    // The current event
    $event = Event::find($id);

    // Find related, upcoming events
    $tags = $event->tags;

    $relatedEvents = Event::where('startDate', '>=', Carbon::now())
    ->where(function ($query) use ($event) {
        $query->where('hostedBy', $event->hostedBy);
        $query->orWhere('type', $event->hostedBy);
        $query->orWhere('category', $event->hostedBy);
        $query->orWhere('sector', $event->hostedBy);
        $query->orWhereHas('tags', function ($query) use ($tags) {
            $query->where('slug', $tags->slug);
        });
    })
    ->toSql();

    dd($relatedEvents);
}
```

But with this attempt, I get undefined variable `$tags`

Can you have many nested queries?

This is because I needed to check fields but also needed to compare tags given to the event.

Also, what do I do if the current article has no tags at all?

**Update**

```
public function show($id)
{
    // The current event
    $event = Event::find($id);

    // Find related, upcoming events
    $tags = $event->tags;

    $relatedEvents = Event::where('startDate', '>=', Carbon::now())
    ->where(function ($query) use ($event, $tags) {
        $query->where('hostedBy', $event->hostedBy);
        $query->orWhere('type', $event->type);
        $query->orWhere('category', $event->category);
        $query->orWhere('sector', $event->sector);
        $query->orWhereHas('tags', function ($query) use ($tags) {
            foreach ($tags as $tag) {
                $query->where('slug', $tag->slug);
            }
        });
    })
    ->orderBy('startDate', 'dsc')
    ->toSql();

    dd($relatedEvents);
}
```

I need to test this, but as there could be multiple tags, I looped through them.

Answer (score 1):

Try this. You need to pass $tags variable in first use

```
 $relatedEvents = Event::where('startDate', '>=', Carbon::now())
    ->where(function ($query) use ($event, $tags) {
        $query->where('hostedBy', $event->hostedBy);
        $query->orWhere('type', $event->hostedBy);
        $query->orWhere('category', $event->hostedBy);
        $query->orWhere('sector', $event->hostedBy);
        $query->orWhereHas('tags', function ($query) use ($tags) {
            $query->where('slug', $tags->slug);
        });
    })
    ->toSql();
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass `tags` from first where

```
$relatedEvents = Event::where('startDate', '>=', Carbon::now())
    ->where(function ($query) use ($event, $tags) { // add tags here
        $query->where('hostedBy', $event->hostedBy);
        $query->orWhere('type', $event->hostedBy);
        $query->orWhere('category', $event->hostedBy);
        $query->orWhere('sector', $event->hostedBy);
        $query->orWhereHas('tags', function ($query) use ($tags) {
            $query->where('slug', $tags->slug);
        });
    })
    ->toSql();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$query->orWhereHas('tags', function ($q) use ($tags) {
        $q->where('slug', $tags->slug);
    });
```

what kind of relationship you defined between event and tags. I think its has many, so in that case, you should use $q->whereIn('slug', $tags->slug);

otherwise

orWhereHas('tags'); is enough.

Comment: try using ->with('tags') as first query.